# Is it possible to make subsequent WebClient calls when emitting flux items?

Tags: kotlin, api-design, spring-webflux

I'm working with an API that only displays an event's venue id in the response when performing an event search API call. I'm looking to see if there's a way to make a Spring WebClient request to fetch the venue information as Flux items are being emitted.

```
val events =  eventService.fetchEventsByLocation(lat,lon,radius)
            .flatMapIterable { eventResponse ->  EventTransformer.map(eventResponse)}
            .doOnNext { transformedEvent -> this.repository.save(transformedEvent) }


fun fetchEventsByLocation(lat:Double?,lon:Double?,radius:Double?): Mono<EventResponse> {

    val builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath(SEARCH_EVENTS)
            .queryParam("categories", "103")
            .queryParam("location.within", 20.toString() + "mi")
            .queryParam("location.latitude", lat)
            .queryParam("location.longitude", lon)
            .queryParam("token",apiKey)

    return this.webClient.get()
            .uri(builder.toUriString())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap { response -> response.bodyToMono(String::class.java) }
            .map { response -> transform(response) }
}

 fun fetchEventVenue(id:String?): Mono<Venue> {
    val builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath(VENUES + id)
            .queryParam("token",apiKey)

    return this.webClient.get()
            .uri(builder.toUriString())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap { response -> response.bodyToMono(Venue::class.java) }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doOnNext` is an intermediate operation. Without a terminal operation (such as `subscribe`), the stream isn't consumed.

Comment: Using `doOnNext` does make it possible to make subsequent API calls while flux items are emitted, but my entire situation is a bit more complicated than that. I'll revise make question to better layout my situation.